# unable to transfer objects using zend2 EventManager

Tags: php, events, zend-framework2

I am using **zend2 event manager** to trigger an event. I then attach a callback to the listener for that event.

the code works up to this point, the problem  is that I am unable to transfer objects with the trigger.

I keep getting the following message;

```
Call to a member function getId() on a non-object
```

below is my code;

**the Trigger:**

```
use ZfcBase\EventManager\EventProvider as eventManger;

 //code/method that gets the sender's object not shown here;

class EventTriggers  extends eventManger 
{

    public function triggerEvent()
        {   
           // var_dump($this->getSender()->getId())

            $this->getEventManager()->trigger(__FUNCTION__, $this, array('sender'   => $this->getSender()->getId(),
                                                                         'receiver' => 11));
        }

}
```

please note that if I **var_dump** the **$this->getSender()->getId()** it returns the Id. however once place on the trigger the values no longer show

**The Listener** (held in another class and accessed via the sharedEventManger)

```
use Zend\EventManager\SharedEventManager;

$sharedEvent = new SharedEventManager;
        $sharedEvent->attach('Messages\Models\EventTriggers', 'triggerEvent', function($e) {
            $event  = $e->getName();
            $target = get_class($e->getTarget());

             $params = $e->getParams();

            var_dump($params); die();
            printf(
                '%s called on %s, using params %s',
                $event,
                $target,
                $params
            );
        });

        $event = new EventTriggers();
        $event->getEventManager()->setSharedManager($sharedEvent);

        $event->triggerEvent();
```

the receiver Id shows up in the above code. the only value that does not appear is the sender object

would really appreciate some advice on what I have done wrong.

Comment: this is strange if `getSender()` is a public method try accessing it inside the event handler `$e->getTarget()->getSender()->getId()` see what happens

Answer (score 0):

It might be that `$this` points to the wrong object.

Try it once like this:

```
public function triggerEvent()
{   
    $sender_id = $this->getSender()->getId();
    $this->getEventManager()->trigger(__FUNCTION__, $this, array(
        'sender'   => $sender_id,
        'receiver' => 11
    ));
}
```

Comment: Hi Wilt, thanks for responce. i tried it but it still does not return an object.the object is simply not being passed on

Comment: @PaulKendal "but it still does not return an object" - you are calling `getId()` so surely this is a `string` or `int`?

Comment: sorry. i tried to return both a string and an object i.e $this->getSender() or $this->getSender()->getId() . it is not returning anything

Comment: You did say that when you do the `var_dump`, it returns the `id`. So now `$sender_id` does not have any value?

Comment: hi Kunal. i commented out the var_dump when i performed the trigger. i only used the uncommented var_dump when i wanted to see if the sender object actually had a values